# How Do I Create a Google Chrome Extension that autofills username/password when I Click the icon?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, autofill, password-encryption

I am having problems figuring out what Is wrong with my code so far because when I click the icon, it says that I run both background.js as well as autofill.js. But does not autofill the gmail site. This is my first chrome extension as well as working with javascript. my ultimate goal is that it can autofill all sites (not just gmail)  and be able to store/read all the passwords on a .txt file. Another thing is that when i try to run this code is says that something is wrong with my autofill.js file and gives me the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null. This is for autofill.js right under the comment //fills in your username and password.
Thanks for taking your time to help me out and anything input would help me because I am stuck and hit a wall

manifest.json:

```
   {
  "name": "Test",
  "manifest_version": 2,    
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "This is a Chrome extension that will autofill passwords",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",     
    "default_popup":"popup.html",
    "default_title": "PasswordFill" 
  },


//********************************************************************* 
//declaring the permissions that will be used in this extension

 "permissions": ["*://*.google.com/", "tabs", "activeTab", "*://*.yahoo.com/"],

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js", "autofill.js"] 
  },


//********************************************************************* 
/* Content scripts are JavaScript files that run in the context of web pages. By using the standard Document Object Model (DOM), they can read details of the web pages the browser visits, or make changes to them */

"content_scripts": [
    {

//Specifies which pages this content script will be injected into
    "matches": ["https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLoginAuth"], 

//The list of JavaScript files to be injected into matching pages
    "js": ["autofill.js"], //was background.js

//Controls when the files at "js" are being injected
    "run_at": "document_end",

    "all_frames": true
    }
]


}
```

background.js:

```
     console.log("Background.js Started .. "); //for debug purpose so i can see it in the console log

    chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) { //Starts when User Clicks on ICON



      chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: 'autofill.js'});

      console.log("Script Executed .. "); // Notification on Completion
    });
```

autofill.js:

```
console.log("Autofill.js Started .. "); //for debug purpose so i can see it in the console log

//define username and password

var myUsername = 'McAfee.sdp';

var myPassword = 'baskin310';





//finds the fields in your login form

var loginField = document.getElementById('Email');

var passwordField = document.getElementById('Passwd');





//fills in your username and password

loginField.value = myUsername;

passwordField.value = myPassword;





//automatically submits the login form

var loginForm = document.getElementById ('signIn');

loginForm.submit();
```

Comment: Did you figure out the problem? @user3409109

Answer (score 1):

You should take some time and read the development [guides](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview) first. Make sure you understand how [debugging](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging) extensions works.

Also, as a general rule, if your script crashes at some line of code, execution will stop and the extension will most likely fail at whatever you wanted it to do (depends on where the crash happens) - just like in any other application.

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null.

That error tells you that you're trying to "access" (set) the property of a "missing" (null) object. `loginField.value = myUsername;` tries to access `value` of `loginField` so you can easily deduce that `loginField` is null which, in turn, means that `var loginField = document.getElementById('Email');` didn't really work. But don't take my word for it, learn to debug it yourself.

Why it fails is a different story: extensions are "sandboxed" and can't run around changing page content whenever they feel like - you have "content scripts" for that. Go back to the docs and read the [overview](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview) and [content scripts sections](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts).

In your specific case:

- the only background script file should be background.js; remove autofill.js
- make use of event pages instead of background ones whenever possible
- autofill.js is a content script and you have it added to the manifest. no need to use programatic injection using `chrome.tabs.executeScript`
- learn how to communicate between backgroud/toolbar and content scripts - you'll need it
- your extension needs permission to access `chrome.tabs.* so add "tabs" to the list of permissions in your extension manifest